# Compile error: "cannot find symbol"

Tags: java

I am writing a coin flipping program for a class. I am having a problem getting the text to center in each of the grids. The grid layout is 3 x 3 but the text "H" or "T" in each grid is left justified. Here is the code for that creates the grid.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class Lab3Panel extends JPanel {

    Lab3Panel() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3, 1, 1));

        Lab3Label[] label = new Lab3Label[9];
        label.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        label.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            label[i] = new Lab3Label(i);
            add(label[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Lab3Panel.java:15: error: cannot find symbol label.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                                                  ^
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling `setHorizontalTextPosition` method on the array object while you should be calling it on one of its entries.

Something like: `label[0].setHorizontalTextPosition`

But to be able to compile the above statement the class `Lab3Label` must define or inherit the method `setHorizontalTextPosition` from one of it's super classes.

I think this is what you need:

```
Lab3Label[] label = new Lab3Label[9];
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    label[i] = new Lab3Label(i);
    label[i].setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    label[i].setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    add(label[i]);
}
```

Comment: are you saying to move the method inside of the for loop?

Comment: "`Lab3Label` instance the class should extends `JLabel` instead of `JPanel`." not mentioned in the code that `Lab3Label` does not extend from `JLabel`